# ReadBeanPHP не хочет передавать запись в переменную

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, php7

RedBeanPHP

```
$1 = R::findOne('messages', 'user_2 = ?', array(NULL));
print_r($1);
```

Ничего не выводит. MariaDB

```
id = 1
user_1 = 1@mail.ru
user_2 = NULL
messageline = 1231
tags = a:0:{}
```

Запрос в логе причём есть:

```
SELECT `messages`.*  FROM `messages`  WHERE user_2 = NULL LIMIT 1   -- keep-cache
```

Comment: Можно узнать причём тут `phpmyadmin`?

Comment: @Сергей-Мишин Лог из него.

Comment: Какой лог? Данные вы пытаетесь заносить в БД. phpmyadmin - не БД

Comment: MariaDB. Я написал. phpmyadmin у меня стоит просто. Это же надо упомянуть?

Comment: Нет, зачем. Он к вопросу никак не относится

Answer (score 0):

```
R::findOne('messages', `user_2 = ?`, array(NULL));
```

Перепутал `'` c `` ` ``.